# Не подключается класс, автозагрузчиком

Tags: php, ооп

Есть структура:

[image: структура проекта]

Есть файл index.php со следующим кодом.

```
<?php
require 'autoload.php';
use Config;
$data = Config::getConfig();
echo $data;
?>
```

и есть автозагрузчик в котором реализовано простое условие, проверяющее, если мы подключаем класс `Config` то идти за ним по одному пути, если нет - по другому.

Вот его код:

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    echo $class_name;
    if ($class_name == "Config"):
        echo "con";
        $configPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config/' . $class_name . '.php';
        $str = str_replace("\\", "/", $configPath);
    else:
        echo "no conf";
        $corePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Core/' . $class_name . '/' . $class_name . '.php';
        $str = str_replace("\\", "/", $corePath);
    endif;
    echo $str;
    require_once($str);
});
```

Имя подключаемого класса:
[image: имя подключаемого класса]

В условие я захожу правильно. Получаю ошибку о том что он не может найти класс. В чем может быть проблема?

Также буду благодарен если кто-то подскажет толковую проверку на подключаемый класс, то что у меня - мне кажется костылем.

Если в браузере перейти по тому пути который в итоге лежит в переменной `$str;`, для конфига - файл есть.

Сама ошибка:
[image: ошибка]
[image: путь к файлу]

Вкратце о данном проекте - я пытаюсь разобраться в том как работают пространства имен, как их правильно использовать, и вообще разобраться нормально в ООП. Я знаю что есть композер, я знаю для чего он предназначен. Но. Я. Хочу. Научиться. Правильно. Юзать. Пространства. Имен. Не зная этого, в моем понимании нет смысла браться за композер и фреймворки. Так что либо помогите найти ошибку, либо проходите мимо.

Comment: Почему composer`ом не пользуетесь? зачем опять изобретать велосипед?

Comment: Может потому что я из сторонних библиотек использую только ORM RedBeans, которая подключается одной строчкой? И все. Или для нее тоже надо композер? Или чтобы сделать require одного файла - тоже композер надо?

Comment: А что у вас выводит `echo $class_name;`? наверное, `Config\Config`?

Comment: обновил вопрос, смотрите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В блоке `use` вы сейчас подключаете не имя класса, а пространство имен:

```
use Config;
```

Чтобы теперь достучаться до класса, нужно это пространство имен указать перед классом:

```
$data = Config\Config::getConfig();
```

Чтобы подключить именно имя класса, нужно написать так:

```
use Config\Config;
...
$data = Config::getConfig();
```

Первый случай бывает полезен, когда у вас большая вложенность, например, есть пространство имен и в нем несколько классов:

```
namespace app\core\something;

Class class1 {}
Class class2 {}
```

И вы можете там, где нужно, подключить нужную вложенность:

```
use app\core\something;
```

И использовать так:

```
$a = new something\class1();
$b = new something\class2();
```

Теперь по `spl_autoload_register`. В `$class_name` вам должно прилетать именно имя класса + пространство имен. Поэтому вы можете переписать вашу функцию как-то так:

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {

    echo $class_name;     // здесь увидите то, что должно быть:   Config\Config

    $sep = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    // отделим пространство имен от имени класса:
    if($lastNsPos = strrpos($class_name, '\\')){
        $namespace = substr($class_name, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($class_name, $lastNsPos + 1);
    }

    if ($className == "Config"):
        echo "con";
        $configPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $sep . 'config' . $sep . $className . '.php';
        $str = str_replace("\\", "/", $configPath);
    else:
        echo "no conf";
        $corePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Core/' . $class_name . '/' . $class_name . '.php';
        $str = str_replace("\\", "/", $corePath);
    endif;
    echo '<br >' . $str;
    require_once($str);
});
```

Comment: да, то что идет после `else:` я не трогал, там конечно тоже переписать нужно.